# Negative H value in Kruskal Wallis test

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

I've found exactly one source adressing this (and of course didn't save it). It said that in a Kruskal-Wallis this is a consequence of having a large sample with a lot of ties. Seen as I've got about 50,000 respondents and only an 11 point scale variable I'd say I qualify for both. 
What that source didn't say however is how to treat this anomaly. At first I just treated is as if $p > 0.05$ and not significant. however when I loaded the wrong data in my post hoc analysis (the data with the negative H) a lot of the pairwise comparisons turned out to be significant. (even more so then some of the test where the H value had a $p < 0.001$) 
So that made me wonder if I have to treat this negative H value differently. Should I just use a random subsample of data to see whether that has a significant H value or declare the test invalid and just see what happens with post hoc (the latter seems unlikely).
By the way my post hoc consists of a Bonferroni corrected Mann-Whitney U comparison.

Comment: Can you paste in the output you're wondering about? (BTW, you shouldn't use U post hoc after KW, try Dunn's test.)

Comment: The definition formula has a ratio of two quantities both of which involve a sum of squared quantities. The problem comes, I suspect, from using a short-cut which replaces the denominator with its known value *if there are no ties*.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really have a traditional output from a statistical program. Because of tempory limitations I only have excel to work with. (I checked my calculations of course and it works on other data) So I basically constructed a kruskall-Wallis template from scratch.
But going on an example this would be what SPSS would roughly give:<br>
n group 1 9,943; mean rank 24,149<br>
n group 2 10,091; mean rank 24,412<br>
n group 3 9,223; mean rank 24,708<br>
n group 4 8,584; mean rank 24,778<br>
n group 5 8,164; mean rank 25,183<br>
n group 6 3,281; mean rank 25,053<br>
H=-2,2871 df=5

Comment: @mdewey That might indeed have been my mistake. Thanks for the help (you too @gung)

Comment: The Mann-Whitney $U$ (rank sum) test is inappropriate as a *post hoc* test following rejection of Kruskal-Wallis because (a) it uses a different set of ranks (i.e. is effectively analyzing different data), and (b) it does not use the pooled variance implied by the null hypothesis of the Kruskal-Wallis test. [This has been written](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362487) [about repeatedly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108958) [on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111869), so there's lots of places to learn about it. :) Also: Welcome, to CV!

Answer (score 1):

The Kruskal-Wallis $H$ statistic is given by:

$$H=\frac{\frac{12\sum_{i=1}^{k}{n_{i}\left(\bar{R}_{i}-\bar{R}\right)^{2}}}{N\left(N+1\right)}}{1-\frac{\sum{T}}{N^{3}-N}}\text{, where:}$$

$k$ is the number of groups;
$N$ is the number of observations across all groups;
$n_{i}$ is the number of observations in the $i^{th}$ group;
$\bar{R}$ is the mean rank of all observations;
$\bar{R}_{i}$ is the rank sum of observations from the $i^{th}$ group (ranks are across observations from all groups); and
$T=t^{3}-t$ for each set of tied ranks, where $t$ is the number of ties in the set, and $\sum{T}$ is the sum of this quantity across all sets of tied ranks.

When there are no ties $T=0$, the denominator of $H$ simplifies to $1$.

For $N=50,000$ and a uniform distribution of ties across your eleven possible values the denominator of $H$ is approximately:

$$1-\frac{11\left(4545^3-45\right)}{50000^3-50000} \approx 0.9997$$

Assuming a highly skewed distribution of ties—say all but ten observations tied on a single value—the denominator of $H$ is approximately:

$$1-\frac{\left(49,990^3-49,990\right)}{50000^3-50000} \approx 0.0006$$

The most extreme case would be where all $N$ observations were tied on the same value, in which case the denominator of $H$ would simplify to $0$, and $H$ would thus be undefined.

Because the cubed term in $T$ can never be greater than $N^{3}$, I do not think it is possible to obtain a negative value of the denominator, and therefore not possible to obtain a negative value of $H$.

**Conclusion:**

- **It is not possible to obtain a negative value of $H$ by adjusting for ties using Kruskal & Wallis formula for $H$ (Equation 1.2) and their adjustment for ties (Equation 1.3).**
- **Cubing a large $N$ *might* place one's software in the position of trying to calculate beyond its available precision, and numerical inconsistencies might thus result.**

Kruskal, W. H. and Wallis, A. (1952). [Use of ranks in one-criterion variance analysis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2280779). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 47(260):583–621.