# Test statistic for follow up procedure (stepwise step down) of Kruskal Wallis

Tags: post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

When conducting a Kruskall Wallis test, it is possible to follow up the procedure with a post hoc test, looking for homogeneous subsets. My question is which statistic is used to perform this procedure (e.g., is it Chi-Square, z, or the original H)?

Comment: You will want to look at Dunn test (1964) as a post hoc to K-W.  I don't understand your question about which statistic is used.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Dunn's test, or the less well known, but more powerful Conover-Iman test. Both *post hoc* tests (a) perform pairwise comparisons using the same rankings used in the Kruskal-Wallis test (as opposed to just performing a bog-standard rank sum test for each pairwise comparison), and (b) use a pooled variance estimate implied by the Kruskal-Wallis test's null hypothesis. Dunn's test is based on an asymptotic *z* distribution, while the Conover-Iman test is based on an asymptotic *t* distribution.

I am unsure what you mean by "stepwise" or "step down", but implementations of both tests for R ([**dunn.test**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dunn.test/index.html) and [**conover.test**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conover.test/)) and for Stata ([**dunntest**](https://alexisdinno.com/stata/dunntest.html) and [**conovertest**](https://alexisdinno.com/stata/conovertest.html)) include step up and step down [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) and [false discovery rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate) control for these tests.

**References**
Conover, W. J. and Iman, R. L. (1979). [On multiple-comparisons procedures](http://permalink.lanl.gov/object/tr?what=info:lanl-repo/lareport/LA-07677-MS). Technical Report LA-7677-MS, Los Alamos Scientific Laboratory.

Dunn, O. J. (1964). [Multiple comparisons using rank sums](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1080/00401706.1964.10490181). *Technometrics*, 6(3):241–252.

Comment: Thank very much, really  this is really helpful. To be more precise: I'm using SPSS which offers a stepdown stepwise multiple comparisons procedure to follow up a KW test. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_22.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.algorithms/alg_nonparametric_multiple-comparisons_stepwise.htm). This page doesn't really mention which statistic is used to perform the hypothesis tests. Concretely, how would you report this procedure using a statistical formula(e.g., t (5) = 4.32, p < .1). What would take the place of the t when reporting this procedure? Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnGoudbeek Eh... I don't use SPSS, and tend to recommend [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) (it's free, and well documented).

Comment: I know all about R and use it all the time. Great piece of software. But in this case, for all kinds or reasons, SPSS is what I need to use.

Comment: @MartijnGoudbeek SPSS is using methods described in Campbell, G. and Skellings, J. H. (1985). [Nonparametric stepwise multiple comparison procedures](https://sci-hub.tw/). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 80(392):998–1003.

Comment: Thanks, that paper is really helpful. From that paper, it seems they're using the same statistic (H) as in the "omnibus" test. Per the paper:  Step 1. The statistic T(k) tests the equality of all k treatments [...]
 
 Step 2. The statistic T(k-1) is applied to all k subsets of k -
 1 [..]  Etc. Does this make sense?

Comment: $H$ is just the Kruskal-Wallis omnibus test statistic (the nonparametric equivalence of the oneway ANOVA), **and there is no multiple comparisons adjustment for a single omnibus test.** The multiple comparisons procedures enter in for the *post hoc* pairwise tests following a rejection of the Kruskal-Wallis null hypothesis.

Comment: Exactly, so my question still is what the test statistic is that is used in the pairwise tests. I am not trying to be obnoxious here, but  I'm still in the dark. For an ANOVA, you have the F-test, which can be follow by t-test. So what is the equivalent of that t-test here? Thanks again for all your efforts.

Comment: @MartijnGoudbeek I am unfamiliar with the methodology cited in the SPSS documentation. Dunn's test is, I believe, the most common appropriate *post hoc* test.